# What is the correct format of combining two regex with OR operator?

Tags: jquery, regex

The validation message is: "**Input is not valid. It must ends with at least one digit or at least one digit with only two alphabets.**"

So, it should accept this type of strings:

as1 
as1df1 
asd21

as1sd 
asd1d2sd

I was able to write the regex for both part individually.

Regex for first part is (**It must ends with at least one digit**):

```
/[0-9]+$/
```

regex for the second part(**ends with at least one digit with only two alphabets**):

```
/[0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$/
```

For both part, I have used an OR operator. But, unfortunately it is not working.

```
/[0-9]+|[0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]$/
```

What's the correct format for combining two regex with OR operator?

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/zvs8m0c2)

Comment: `/(regex1|regex2)/`

Comment: `/\d+(\w{2})?$/`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you can use:

```
/\d+$/
```

For the second requirement, it's somewhat similar.

```
/d+\w{2}$/
```

If you want exactly one digit and two characters, drop the `+`. However, assuming you want one *or more* digits for the second part, you can then combine both with the `|` metacharacter to get:

```
/\d+(\w{2})?$/
```

Otherwise, you'd need:

```
/(\d+|\d\w{2})$/
```

Here, `\d` is a digit, and `\w` matches ascii and unicode letters, and the underscore.

Comment: @user1896653 I mentioned that the two regular expressions are to be combined with the `|` meta character. Assuming that was your question?